# Possibilities of MS Outlook Web Add-ins on the header/Ribbon in web apps and Independent

Tags: web, outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am working with outlook Web-Addins. Addin type is "ItemRead". Now I want some thing unrelated to mails as in i want to have button on header as i see the skype button on the top.

Also we can create Addin on mail compose. I am not sure if this is possible to have separate buttons on header separate from mail section

example in the image of skype button.

[image]

I have also tried with Outlook Add-in ModuleExtension but cannot seems to be work as expected in outlook web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command controls for invoking add-on are described in [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests) part of the add-in. Those controls will be displayed in predefined place of the UI depend on particular client design (Outlook online, Outlook desktop, etc.). As the developer you are able to set control's setting, such as title, icon and so on, but not the place where control will be displayed. This would be up to Microsoft dev/design team.

*Bottom line:* You are not able to place your control in the specific place of the client interface.

Module extension add-in currently available for Outlook 2016 desktop. There is [request to make it available for Outlook online](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13469784-make-the-module-extension-add-in-available-for-out) which you can upvote if you like.

*Additional Questions:*

> So is it is not possible right right now?

Module extension add-in for Outlook online is not currently available. To place your control into the place you want is not available, either and never will be. This is because of obvious reasons ... can you imagine what's happen with user interface if every extension will be able to modify the UI as it needs? Total disaster.

> Or can you help me with other option ?

Outlook add-in works with single item, as of the controls will appear when item (e-mail, appointment, etc.) selected or compose window invoked, there is nothing you can do.

> Also one more thing that is it possible to store a custom global setting value for the outlook organization using addin or any other way?

To store the settings for particular mailbox, user inside organization, there is [`Office.context.roamingSettings`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/RoamingSettings?product=outlook&version=v1.5) object. If you need some global settings for your app for entire organization, you would set them inside JS part for this particular organization and make the deployment just withing this organization. In case you want to distribute the app via Office store and customize it per organization you may want to write some service which delivers custom settings for add-on on start-up. For example you have rest service which returns custom configuration depend on domain; in this case when add-on invoked you may request custom configuration by sending rest call with user domain and after cache it in mailbox.

Comment: As i am new to addin development but m a js developer so web addins are like perfect solution for me. In this case i want to create a button which should not dependent on mails because only when i open the main the addin button appears, so what if i need a button separate from mail item. So is it is not possible right right now? Or can you help me with other option ? Also one more thing that is it possible to store a custom global setting value for the outlook organization using addin or any other way?

Comment: @AjitHogade I have modified my original answer to address your questions. Please note So is not the forum type of resource and really QandA, which means one question, one answer. If you satisfied with the answer on the original question consider to mark it as "answered". If you have additional questions which are not related to original one, make new post. Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)